# cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

Hola que tal estoy tratando de hacer una peticion a una api con laravel 7 así:

```
Route::get('/api_user', 'UserController@getApi')->name('api_user');
```

En el controlador tengo como lo indica la documentación:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
```

y en el método:

```
public function getApi(){

        $response=Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
        return $response;
    }
```

Pero me sale el error descrito en el titulo. Alguien sabe que solución se le puede dar? De antemano gracias. Anteriormente estaba usando Guzzle pero me marcaba el mismo error

Comment: El problema está en la validación del certificado que hace la librería encargada; nada tiene que ver tu petición HTTP. El certificado es inválido o la entidad certificadora es privada/inválida.

Comment: Entonces que se puede hacer ahí?

Comment: Revisa que PHP tenga acceso a la [información suficiente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17478283/paypal-access-ssl-certificate-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate).